# Сокеты в несколько потоков

Tags: c, многопоточность, сокет

пишу программу на C и нужно реализовать такую штуку: Есть 2 потока, 1 который вынимает из базы запись ( если она есть ) и отсылает по указанному адресу данные через сокет, второй поток стои на приеме данных, т.е. если нам отсылают данные мы через сокет (на том же порту, что и поток для отправки работает) принимаем данные, обрабатываем и записываем в бд. Вопрос следующий, как это реализовать? 2 сокета на одинаковом порту открыть нельзя, по этому я подумал сделать флаг, который был бы false если поток для приема простаивает и в это время отсылал бы данные, но тут загвостка, не понятно по какому условию переключать флаг. Есть ли какое-то решение данного вопроса через потоки?

Comment: А как это «отправить через определённый порт»?

Comment: не понял вашего вопроса. Я имел в виду, что поток отправки и поток приема должны работать на одном порте

Comment: Ну я к тому, что понимаем что такое причём на порте, а отправка на порте это что-то странное оО

Comment: Используйте select,poll,epoll - по вкусу, два сокета не требуется в принципе, это не правильно. По событиям работайте с базой на чтение/запись. И кому отсылает поток? Там должен быть конкретный сокет прицепленного клиента. Делайте пул из изменений, и при коннекте клиента посылайте ему этот пул.. хотя надо понять какая архитектура и схема связи приложения.

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать таким способом один и тот же fd сокета в обоих потоках (posix threads)?

Answer (score 0):

Специально для решения этой проблемы в *NIX существует системный вызов *select*. Когда мы передаём этому вызову некоторый сокет, то *select* информирует нас о том, какое именно событие произошло на сокете:

- если появились данные для чтения - можете их забирать и ложить в БД
- если завершена запись в канал, можете проверить наличие данных для отправки и попытаться их передать.

Рекомендую Вам почитать раздел "6.3. Функция select" в книге У. Р. Стивенс, Б. Феннер, Э. М. Рудофф "UNIX Разработка сетевых приложений"

Comment: А получится на одном сокете и ожидать соединений и передавать через него данные?

Comment: *select* именно для этого и предназначен.

Comment: Может быть я и ошибаюсь, но select предназначен для мультиплексирования множества сокетов, а не перевода одного сокета из состояния ожидания соединений в состояние передачи и обратно.

Comment: Этот системный вызов работает с **множеством** сокетов. Оно так и называется - *socket set*. По **каждому** элементу множества выполняется анализ событий - что произошло на данном сокете - поступили данные, ушли данные, произошла ошибка.

Но ведь множество может состоять из **одного** сокета! И Вы так же будете отслеживать его состояние.

Comment: Ага, если это серверный сокет, принимающий соединения, то единственное событие, которое будет на нём возникать - это событие нового соединения.